# Why is Moment giving me the date of today and not formatting my date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using this filter

```
Vue.filter("toDate", function (value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(Date(value)).format("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm");
    
  }
});
```

The value content is `1529416634`

So the Value should be `2018-06-19 15:57`

But when I pass the date

```
return moment(value).format() //1970-01-18 17:50
```

And with the `Date()` function

```
return moment(Date(value)).format("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm"); //2021-09-18 11:16
```

It gives me the date of today.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Date(x) - returns today's date (w/ any argument)
new Date(x) - parses date from the value

Comment: you want `new Date(value*1000)` - or `moment(value * 1000)`

Comment: hmn i dont see whats wrong, `1529416634` IS `Sun Jan 18 1970 17:50:16 GMT+0100` or what?!

Comment: 1529416634000 is `2018-06-19 15:57` though, at least, in your timezone I guess - oops ... john smith replying to johnw2smith - I got confused

Comment: [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor) - *When called as a function, returns a string representation of the current date and time, exactly as `new Date().toString()` does.*

Comment: the trailing zeros is important! "1529416634000" is correct  `2018-06-19 15:57`

Comment: But now with this date `1529662597924` I don't have to same result? It gives me `50443-01-29 06:12`

Answer (score 1):

`moment` and `Date` takes the time in the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

You are currently passing it as the number of `seconds` since the Unix Epoch.

You can do

`return moment(value * 1000).format() //2018-06-19T14:57:14+01:00`

or

`return moment.unix(value).format() //2018-06-19T14:57:14+01:00`

or

`return moment(new Date(value * 1000)).format() //2018-06-19T14:57:14+01:00`

Comment: It worked for the date that I gave... but not with `1529662597924` Should I change something?